# How to edit each line in a text file and change it to an HTML file in python

Tags: python, html

I've got a list of wikipedia links where each link is on a new line. What I want to do is cut the link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) from each line but store it in a variable called "prelink", put the remaining string in a variable called "linkx" where x is the line number, append the html URL tags with "prelink + linkx" between the a href brackets and "linkx" as the name of the link and then append x. (the line number) at the beginning of every line. then, save the file as its name.html instead of name.txt.

This is one of the first programming experiments I've tried, and I'm finding myself hitting my head against the wall. I can get the file open and to read each line, but after that I'm lost.

Comment: Please give an example input and output. Your description is pretty hard to follow. Further, show your effort by providing some code - even if it's not yet working correctly. If you have no idea where to start, look into Python's [string manipulation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/strings.html) documentation. The web is full of good resources.

Comment: I agree with @Falko. Stackoverflow isn't intended to teach you how to code. Google 'python string manipulation tutorial' and roll from there...